# Sets of Linear operators and Uniform Boundedness

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be the function space defined in the following way. A function $x$ belongs to $X$ if and only if the two conditions below are satisfied:

• $x : R → R$ is continuous.

• there exists a compact set $I_x$ of $R$ such that $x(t) = 0$ for every $t ∈ R$ \ $I_x$

[image]

How can we show that, for every $x ∈ X$, there exists $c_x > 0$ such that $sup_{
 n∈N}$ $|T_nx| ≤ c_x$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there are finitely many $n$ such that $n\in I_{x}$, but now for other $n$, we have $|T_{n}x|\leq\displaystyle\int_{I_{x}}|x(s)|ds$ since those other $n$ lie outside the interval $I_{x}$, so the integration can be taken only on $I_{x}$. But then $|T_{n}x|\leq|I_{x}|\|x\|$, in other words, $\sup_{n}|T_{n}x|=M_{x}<\infty$.

Comment: Do you think you could explain the easy part to me?

Comment: Wait a minute, so your question is not complete, isn't it? Anyway, I have explained the so called $c_{x}$ (or $M_{x}$ in my notation).

Comment: Yes, I removed a part asking to show that $lim_n→∞$ $||T_n|| = ∞$ and then use that with the above question to show that X isn't a Banach space (using Uniform boundedness) as I was told to only include one singular question at a time on stack exchange. Thank you for your help though, it is very clear.